# Unable to open google app engine application on my custom domain

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, flask

I have a React + Flask application deployed on Google App Engine and mapped to my custom domain. I deployed a new version 3 days ago, it was working properly until today. On my custom domain, I cannot open some pages. I checked the console, apparently, the application were unable to load the `js` packages, and one of the error is

`GET https://MY_DOMAIN/static/js/main.4eaaa8ad.chunk.js net :: ERR_ABORTED 404`.

I also check the App Engine version instance, the `MY_PROJECT.appsport.com` is working properly.

I was wondering whether I made an error on the app.yaml file or I mapped the DNS incorrectly.

My app.yaml is this :

```
runtime: python37
env: standard

default_expiration: '5m'

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app --timeout 150

instance_class: F4

automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 5
  min_instances: 1
  min_pending_latency: '5s'
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.75

inbound_services:
  - warmup

handlers:
  - url: /static/js/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/js/\1
    upload: build/static/js/(.*)
  - url: /static/css/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/css/\1
    upload: build/static/css/(.*)
  - url: /static/media/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/media/\1
    upload: build/static/media/(.*)
  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico)$
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
```

I have also noticed that I actually did not set the `$PORT` environment variable, could this be a potential problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `static_dir` in handlers of your `app.yaml` to serve the static files of your application:

```
handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: build/static/
  - url: /static/js/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/js/\1
    upload: build/static/js/(.*)
  - url: /static/css/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/css/\1
    upload: build/static/css/(.*)
  - url: /static/media/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/media/\1
    upload: build/static/media/(.*)
  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico)$
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. May I ask where should I add the static_dir in the handlers, since the order of handlers matters.